# src/zone-flags.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation after upgrading to Ionic 5, or capacitor 5

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I upgraded my Ionic 4 application by these two commands:

```sh
# Upgrading to Ionic 5
npm install @ionic/angular@latest @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest --save

# Upgrading to Angular 9
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

And when I did `ionic serve`, I started getting this error:

```
> ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] chunk {} 0.js, 0.js.map () 22.1 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 25.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] 
[ng] ERROR in ./src/zone-flags.ts
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
[ng] Error: /Users/shashank/Projects/my-app/mobile-app/src/zone-flags.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
[ng]     at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/shashank/Projects/my-app/mobile-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:909:23)
[ng]     at plugin.done.then (/Users/shashank/Projects/my-app/mobile-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
[ng]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The fix is to change the following line in `mobile-app/src/polyfills.ts`:

**From:**

```
import './zone-flags.ts';
```

**To:**

```
import './zone-flags';
```

Comment: Thanks, @elnezah. While I was not able to find the answer myself as well (for an hour or so), looking at the error, I understood that this is something related to polyfills. So I created a new Angular & Ionic app and compared the files one by one and found the difference.